# How to detect if Android device has QWERTY keypad

Tags: android, keypad, qwerty

I am new to Android. I want to detect, through code, whether my android device has QWERTY keypad and camera or not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **check keypad existence**

Fetch the [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) object using

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
```

...and then look at the [`keyboard`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard) field.

If they value of [`keyboard`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard) is not [KEYBOARD_NOKEYS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#KEYBOARD_NOKEYS), the user has a hardware keyboard.

And for **hardware Camera**...

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
}
```

Comment: for keypad check  I used like System.out.println( config.keyboared);it returned 2 what it means?

Comment: Look at `KEYBOARD_*` constants at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard). 2 stays for KEYBOARD_QWERTY, so you have QWERTY one